# Rotating Rectangle and calculating corner

Tags: java, math, user-interface, graphics

I'm rotating a rectangle and now want to calculate the new position of the upper left corner.

my current calculation is:

```
Point upLeft = new Point(
        // x-coordinate
                (int) Math.round((oldx * Math.cos(objectAngleRad))
                        - (oldy * Math.sin(objectAngleRad))),
                // y-coordinate
                (int) Math.round((oldx * Math.sin(objectAngleRad))
                        + (oldy * Math.cos(objectAngleRad))));
```

The calculation doesn't work. Can somebody see the error?

Comment: Didn't even try your code, but wanted to ask why aren't you using affine? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html

Comment: My friend implemented the rotation i only get the angle and the current position of the rectangle.

Comment: but maybe we can try changing the code. Thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subtract the midpoint of the rectangle before you rotate it and then add it back afterwards, otherwise you're rotating the corner about the origin (0,0)

```
Point upLeft = new Point(
    // x-coordinate
        (int) Math.round(midx + ((oldx-midx) * Math.cos(objectAngleRad))
                              - ((oldy-midy) * Math.sin(objectAngleRad))),
    // y-coordinate
        (int) Math.round(midy + ((oldx-midx) * Math.sin(objectAngleRad))
                              + ((oldy-midy) * Math.cos(objectAngleRad))));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with a little error about 10pi I will try to fix it and post the working version afterwards.

Comment: It works I only had a mistake in my mid calculation.